# "Something is playing in the wind...": The Fixtures?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a reason why a great many things are called [*fixtures*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fixtures): such things are meant to be securely fixed, attached, usually to a surface. Whereas a *loose* fixture refers to the state of that object, the [*play*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=play) is rather possibly the range of motion available to the object in that state:

> *play* n.
>
> [...]
>
> 9. Movement or space for movement, as of mechanical parts.
>
> [ [*American Heritage Dictionary of the English language*](https://ahdictionary.com/) ]

That state and the space for movement are conditions where noise may occur when a force sets the object in motion. So if someone comments about hearing a rattle in the wind, couldn't they say that "*something is(the fixtures are) playing in the wind*", with no reference to music or an animal running around or what not? Could they say that *there's a play with some fixtures* or do the more casual meanings of *play* completely upstage the *motion* sense here? Is "*(the sound of) a loose fixture in the wind*" the better way to express this; would that be confused with a *fixture (*set/let*) loose in the wind*, as in completely free from any restraint and not just sort of "hanging"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this usage, *play* is the movement possible of some object in an area between two fixed surfaces. Here is an example: [***Bearing (mechanical)***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_%28mechanical%29#Play)

> For example, a 10 mm shaft in a 12 mm hole has 2 mm play.

As such, this meaning cannot apply to the wind, as in

> something that is *playing* in the wind

because the wind does not have fixed surfaces.

Actually, *play* is the ability to move, but it does not imply that the movement is actually happening.

What you are describing seems more like *dancing* in the wind.

Comment: Agreed; _play_ is just a noun, and the questioner is trying to verb it.  The fixtures **have** play, but they **are** just _moving_ or _rattling_ or _flapping_ or _shaking_ or whatever.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks! It helps to know things "have play". I have a reflex from another language where I can say both "there is a play" and the object "has a play"; the verb would be weaker. But please do note though that _to play_ carries the sense I was talking about too i.e. sense 11 in AH(_play_ link in Q).

Comment: Thank you! Do you think then that "something is playing on the/against the wall" would work? And can we describe a door knocker as having a _play_ (by design)? I didn't know _dancing_ would work here, despite there being nothing playing! Thanks again!

Comment: @Amphiteóth - You're right, the dictionary does list it as a verb.  I have to say that in all my life I don't think I've ever heard it used as a verb.  Usually I'd just use it as a noun, like "There's a lot of play in this worn-out joint."